# WebStorm with mulitple projects attached - open a tool window for a certain project

Tags: webstorm

I've got a project with four different repositories.

Recently, instead of opening four different windows, I've decided to open up the most important repo and attach to it the other projects.

However, it seems all of WebStorm's tool windows (VCS et cetera) are still bound to the main project, and there doesn't seem to be a convenient way to manage all the projects from one WebStorm instance.

Is it possible to, for example, open the VCS tool window and easily switch it focus between projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it's not. Attaching projects to current one is more or less equal to adding content roots, it's a single project for the IDE. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/opening-reopening-and-closing-projects.html#428b6b3d

Related feature requests:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39009

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39015

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218888

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217413